# Inserting image in Blobstore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, blobstore

I'm developping a Google App Engine project.In fact, i want to save the images in the blobstore,
after that,i recover the blob key and the serving url, and i store them  in an Demand entity in Datastore.

My jsp file is :

```
  <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
  <%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.*"%>
  <%@ page import="com.Upload"%>
  <%
  BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
   %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-narrow">
  <div class="masthead">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Accueil</a></li>
   <li><a href="#upload">Upload</a></li>
  </ul>
   <h3 class="muted">Cloud Uploader</h3>
  </div>
  <hr />

  <form
   action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/") %>"
   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>
   <label>Fichier à envoyer : <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" /></label>
   </p>
   <div class="form-actions">
   <input type="submit" class="btn" />
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My servlet which handles the request:

```
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
     throws IOException, ServletException { 
     this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/UploadForm.jsp").forward(req, resp);}


     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException, ServletException {  
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

     Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);

    System.out.println(blobKeys.get(0).toString());//No result 

    DataManager dat=new DataManager(); // this class contains DemandCreate method

     String personPhotoServingUrl=         imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKeys.get(0)));                       
     String personPhotoBlobKey=blobKeys.get(0).toString();

    dat.DemandCreate("id3", "", "", "", "", 1, "", "", 3031, "", "", personPhotoBlobKey,    personPhotoServingUrl);// this method enables user to store data in Datasotre using Objectify..

    resp.sendRedirect("/");}
```

The problem is when i upload an image,it works fine, the blob and the image is found in the BlobInfo entity but  no result added in my Demand entity (no new insertion in this entity).
I tried  to print the  blob key of the image inserted :

```
    System.out.println(blobKeys.get(0).toString());//No result
```

But, no result.
Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, it's due to the successpath which had a value "/" in the jsp file:

```
 <form
 action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/") %>"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The successPath is relative URL which will be invoked after the user successfully  uploads a blob.
So when blob is succesfully uploaded,the jsp returns to the principal directory and doesn't execute the code of the doPost() method.For that reason, i've solved the issue by copying the code of the  doPost method to  other servlet named for exemple NewDemandHandler and editing the successpath  to the relative path of this servlet:

```
  <form
 action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/NewDemandHandler") %>"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

blobs is a Map. Do you want the key to the map blobs or a List of BlobKeys?

To get a key to the map you could do:

blob.keySet().toArray()[0]

To get a List of BlobKeys you could do:

blob.get(blob.keySet().toArray()[0]).get(0).toString()

Answer (score 0):

You save blob data to `blobs`, not to `blobKeys`.

Imho you should be doing this:

```
System.out.println(blobs.get("uploadedFile").toString());
```

Comment: i've tried what you've said but unfortunately no result also.